# TestActorRef: Could not get the underlyingActor, says Nothing

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-testkit

I am trying to write my first `ScalaTest` for following `Actor`

```
object Runner {
  def props(race: Race) = Props(classOf[Runner], race)
}

class Runner(race: Race) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import context.dispatcher

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = context.parent ! RestartRunner

  override def receive: Receive = LoggingReceive {
    case Start => {
      log.debug("running...")
      for (i <- 1 to 3) {
        Thread.sleep(200)
      }
      throw new RuntimeException("MarathonRunner is tired")
    }

    case StartWithFuture =>
      log.debug("I am starting to run")
      race.start pipeTo self

    case Failure(throwable) => throw throwable

    case Stop =>
      log.debug("stopping runner")
      context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

So, I do

```
import akka.actor.{Props, ActorSystem}
import akka.testkit.{TestActorRef, TestKit}
import org.scalatest._

class RunnerSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test"))
with WordSpecLike
with MustMatchers {
  "A Runner Actor" must {
    val runner = TestActorRef(Props(new Runner(new Marathon)))
    "receive messages" in {
      runner ! Start
      runner.under <== says Nothing (see attachment)
    }
  }
}
```

but what I see is

[image]

Why don't I get back the `Runner Actor`?

Answer (score 3):

Since `Props` is untyped it does not know which type of actor (in your case `Runner`) it will build. Consequently, the `TestActorRef` cannot infer the type either. This is why you need to explicitly state the type of the underlying actor when constructing your `TestActorRef` using

```
val runner = TestActorRef[Runner](Props(new Runner(new Marathon)))
```

In case your actor did not require any parameters, this could even be shortened to

```
val runner = TestActorRef[Runner]
```

However, since `Nothing` is actually the base class of every scala type, the underlying actor is the same in either case. So if changing the `TestActorRef` definition were not possible it could also be casted to yield a `Runner`.

```
runner.underlyingActor.asInstanceOf[Runner]
```